# Android: FloatingActionButton could not be instantiated

Tags: android, floating-action-button

I am trying to use Floating Action Button(FAB) in my application.
However, when I am declaring the same I get the error:

```
android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton could not be instantiated.
```

I have added following commands to my gradle file:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
```

I have also tried with adding following to my style parent:

```
parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat"
```

Also tried having my Activity class `extend Activity` as well as `AppCompatActivity`.

Am I missing something? Pls. help

Comment: Every thing looks fine,to find root cause post your complete code so we will help in better way.

Comment: make sure should be "compileSdkVersion 23"

Comment: whats your classpath `com.android.tools.build:gradle:` ?

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya: Thanks a lot sir. problem is resolved. I had it as 1.3.0 instead of 1.5.0. You might want to post your solution as an answer to help me mark it as accepted answer.

Comment: @RituRaj Move ahead .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Android build system uses the Android Plugin for Gradle to support
>   building Android applications with the Gradle build toolkit. The
>   plugin runs independent of Android Studio so the plugin and the Gradle
>   build system can be updated independently of Android Studio.

For `FloatingActionButton` requirement

Please update your `classpath`

```
  dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'

    }
```

Comment: I have it that way but still get the same error. From console, I have gradle 2.8

Answer (score 0):

Must have :

```
compileSdkVersion 23
```

&

```
 dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'

        }
```