# Gradle Dependency Conflict, Version for app 26.1.0 and test app 27.1.1

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I am working on an android app having the navigation drawer. All things are working when When I got error of Floating action bar not  found.

I have searched about that on stack overflow [Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35169837/android-floatingactionbutton-could-not-be-instantiated)

and I found solution to add this dependency in the code implementation **'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'**

After I added I found another error of conflict between dependencies.

the Links I have searched to resolve my problems [Link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50089436/errorexecution-failed-for-task-apppredebugandroidtestbuild-when-tried-to), [Link 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50120459/resolved-versions-for-app-26-1-0-and-test-app-27-1-1-differ),
 [Link 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36833606/android-support-library-error-after-updating-to-23-3-0)

Here is my app build.gradle Dependencies

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.0.4'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.0.4'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}

android {
compileSdkVersion 26
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.usmanali.medicineinvent"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}
```

The other gradle file

```
    buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
}
}
```

Comment: post the error you got

Comment: checkout [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49093399/7804719) answer. I have also faced this problem but i have solved it by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49093399/7804719) solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [com.android.support:support-v4 has different version for the compile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52114947/com-android-supportsupport-v4-has-different-version-for-the-compile)